# The center of a ring $R$ is a subring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

> The center of a ring is $\{z \in R \mid zr=rz\text{ for all }r \in R\}$. Prove that the center of a ring is a subring that contains the identity.

I started like this.
Proof:  Let $C =\{z \in R \mid zr=rz\text{ for all }r \in R\}$. Let $a ,b \in C$ then $ar-br = ra-rb$ which implies that $(a-b)r = r(a-b) \in C$.

This is where my difficulty is, $arbr = rarb$, how do I show that the product $ab$ is in the center? Also how does this help me show that the identity is in the subring?

Answer (score 1):

First, the identity is clearly in the center since part of the definition of an identity element is that it commutes with every other element. 
Secondly, if $a,b \in C$ then your task is to show that $ab \in C$. Note that for any $r \in R$:
$rab=(ra)b=(ar)b=a(rb)=a(br)=abr$. Does this help?

Comment: You also need to check closure under addition and taking additive inverses. Meaning that if $a,b \in C$ you want to show $a+b \in C$ and $-a \in C$.